# How to connect to an existing sqlite database file in Apache Cordova

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have created the database records file using sqlite manager in Firefox.

How can I connect to the created database file using Apache Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Check sqlite storage adapter plugin for Cordova.

[Cordova/PhoneGap sqlite storage adapter](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)